# How do I setup dependent factories using Factory Boy and Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, factory-boy

What is the correct way to use factory boy with Flask-SQLAlchemy and Foreign Key constraints?

Consider the following Flask SQLAlchemy Model setup:

```
# coding=utf-8
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# ------------------------------
#   SQLAlchemy Table Models
# ------------------------------
class User(db.Model):
    """ A SQLAlchemy simple model class who represents a user with a ForeignKey Constraint"""
    __tablename__ = 'UserTable'

    user_pk = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(20))
    group_fk = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("GroupTable.group_pk"), nullable=False)


class Group(db.Model):
    """ A SQLAlchemy simple model class who represents a user """
    __tablename__ = 'GroupTable'

    group_pk = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)


# -------------------------
#   Create the SQL tables
# -------------------------
db.create_all()
```

**The User schema requires a Group foreign key when creating a new user.**  Since the Group primary key is assigned from the database, the factory would need to commit a group entry and get the entry's primary key so that it can provide it to the new User.

**How do I create a group, save it to the DB, and provide it's key to the User Factory?**

[Factory Boy has examples for dealing with Foreign Keys](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes.html#dependent-objects-foreignkey)  but they don't seem to apply to SQLAlchemy.  Here are the factories and the failure point:

```
# ----------------------------------------
#   Factory-Boy User and Group Factories
# ----------------------------------------
from factory import alchemy, Sequence, RelatedFactory


class GroupFactory(alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Group
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session  # the SQLAlchemy session object

    name = Sequence(lambda n: "Group {}".format(n))
    # group_pk = Sequence(lambda n: n)


class UserFactory(alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session  # the SQLAlchemy session object

    user_pk = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    name = Sequence(lambda n: u'User %d' % n)  # coding=utf-8
    group_fk = RelatedFactory(GroupFactory)


# ----------------------
#   Factory tests
# ----------------------
# Create a new Group from our factory
group_from_factory = GroupFactory(name='a new group name')
assert group_from_factory.group_pk is None
# Save it to our DB
db.session.add(group_from_factory)
db.session.commit()

# Verify that Group Saved correctly to DB
group_from_db = db.session.query(Group).filter(Group.group_pk == group_from_factory.group_pk).first()
assert group_from_db.group_pk is not None
assert group_from_db.name == 'a new group name'
assert group_from_db.group_pk == group_from_factory.group_pk

# Create a new User from our factory
user_from_factory = UserFactory()
db.session.add(user_from_factory)
# ----------------------------------------------
#   FAILS AT COMMIT() - NOT NULL constraint failed (group_fk is null)
# ----------------------------------------------
db.session.commit()

assert user_from_factory.user_pk is not None
assert user_from_factory.name is not None
assert user_from_factory.group_fk is not None
```

Comment: **SubFactory** doesn't work.  See comments on this.  According to the Factory Boy api it should, but it doesn't which is why I posted on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue comes from using a `RelatedFactory`: those are intended for **reverse** `ForeignKey` relations (e.g if you want to build a `Group` object which already contains a `User`).

For a direct `ForeignKey` - like the relation from `User` to `Group`, use a `SubFactory`:

```
class UserFactory(factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session

    # No need to force the user_pk, it is built automatically from the database
    # user_pk = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    name = Sequence(lambda n: u'User %d' % n)  # coding=utf-8
    group_fk = factory.SubFactory(GroupFactory)
```

I'm not very familiar with Flask-SQLAlchemy, but I've just added a small example to the repository (at https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy/tree/master/examples/flask_alchemy) that works yet is quite similar to your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but SubFactory doesn't solve this.  SQL throws an 'unsupported type' error since the SubFactory returns a Group instance instead of an Integer.  So what I need is to communicate the Group.group_pk Integer value to the User.group_fk attribute so that SQL doesn't freak out when it executes the INSERT statement.  Also the Group object returned from SubFactory is **not saved in the database yet**

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'INSERT INTO "UserTable" (name, group_fk) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'User 0', <__main__.Group object at 0x101c20650>)]

Comment: The github code you wrote is great.  It looks like this may be the way to do it.  It requires a change in the SQLAlchemy table model which is why I didn't see SubFactory as a solution.  It's a solution if the table model is constructed in a particular fashion, which is a better construction.  I need more time to review it before I mark the answer, but this is good.

Answer (score 5):

**Xelnor's** git link shows the best answer so far, but it requires changes to the sqlalchemy model.  Here is the finished working copy of my post using Xelnor's solution:

```
# coding=utf-8
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

SQLAlchemy Table Models

```
class User(db.Model):
    """ A SQLAlchemy simple model class who represents a user with a ForeignKey Constraint"""
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(20))

    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'), nullable=False)
```

The 'group' db.relationship is what makes the SubFactory call work.
UserFactory passes group to the User model, which is setup with this
relationship() definition.

```
    group = db.relationship('Group', backref=db.backref('groups', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, name, group):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Group for %r: %s>' % (self.group, self.name)


class Group(db.Model):
    """ A SQLAlchemy simple model class who represents a user """
    __tablename__ = 'group'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Group %r>' % self.name
```

Create the SQL tables

```
db.create_all()
```

Factory-Boy User and Group Factories

```
from factory import alchemy, Sequence, SubFactory, fuzzy


class BaseFactory(alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session


class GroupFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Group
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session  # the SQLAlchemy session object

    name = fuzzy.FuzzyText()


class UserFactory(BaseFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session

    name = fuzzy.FuzzyText()
    group = SubFactory(GroupFactory)
```

Factory tests

```
# Create a new Group from our factory
group_from_factory = GroupFactory(name='a new group name')
assert group_from_factory.id is None
# Save it to our DB
db.session.add(group_from_factory)
db.session.commit()

# Verify that Group Saved correctly to DB
group_from_db = db.session.query(Group).filter(Group.id == group_from_factory.id).first()
assert group_from_db.id is not None
assert group_from_db.name == 'a new group name'
assert group_from_db.id == group_from_factory.id

# Create a new User from our factory
user1_from_factory = UserFactory(name=u'first')
user2_from_factory = UserFactory(name=u'second')
db.session.add(user1_from_factory)
db.session.add(user2_from_factory)
db.session.commit()

assert user1_from_factory.id is not None
assert user1_from_factory.name is not None
assert user1_from_factory.id is not None

assert user2_from_factory.id is not None
assert user2_from_factory.name is not None
assert user2_from_factory.id is not None
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LazyAttribute and a lambda to generate a your new Group and then pull it's 'group_pk' out.

Working version of your code below:

```py
# coding=utf-8
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# ------------------------------
#   SQLAlchemy Table Models
# ------------------------------
class User(db.Model):
    """ A SQLAlchemy simple model class who represents a user with a ForeignKey Constraint"""
    __tablename__ = 'UserTable'

    user_pk = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(20))
    group_fk = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("GroupTable.group_pk"), nullable=False)


class Group(db.Model):
    """ A SQLAlchemy simple model class who represents a user """
    __tablename__ = 'GroupTable'

    group_pk = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)


# -------------------------
#   Create the SQL tables
# -------------------------
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
# ----------------------------------------
#   Factory-Boy User and Group Factories
# ----------------------------------------
from factory import alchemy, Sequence, LazyAttribute


class GroupFactory(alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta(object):
        model = Group
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session  # the SQLAlchemy session object

    name = Sequence(lambda n: "Group {}".format(n))
    group_pk = Sequence(lambda n: n)


class UserFactory(alchemy.SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session  # the SQLAlchemy session object

    user_pk = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    name = Sequence(lambda n: u'User %d' % n)  # coding=utf-8
    group_fk = LazyAttribute(lambda a: GroupFactory().group_pk)


# ----------------------
#   Factory tests
# ----------------------
# Create a new Group from our factory
group_from_factory = GroupFactory(name='a new group name')
# Save it to our DB
db.session.add(group_from_factory)
db.session.commit()

# Verify that Group Saved correctly to DB
group_from_db = db.session.query(Group).filter(Group.group_pk == group_from_factory.group_pk).first()
assert group_from_db.group_pk is not None
assert group_from_db.name == 'a new group name'
assert group_from_db.group_pk == group_from_factory.group_pk

# Create a new User from our factory
user_from_factory = UserFactory()
db.session.add(user_from_factory)
# ----------------------------------------------
#   FAILS AT COMMIT() - NOT NULL constraint failed (group_fk is null)
# ----------------------------------------------
db.session.commit()

assert user_from_factory.user_pk is not None
assert user_from_factory.name is not None
assert user_from_factory.group_fk is not None
```